# Rows in table overlap each other

Tags: tables, miktex

I have problem with putting any simple table in to my document.
Every row is typeset on the same line and they overlap each other.

I'm using Miktex 2.9 on windows.

Is this some kind of bug? Or problem with my configuration?

```
\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ c c c }
 cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\ 
 cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\  
 cell7 & cell8 & cell9    
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

[image: rows overlapped]

Please help.

EDIT1: Document has over 1k lines, so I've upload it on my google drive: [full document](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx6IrwmHqKQneXNUNlVnZ2tCTkE/view?usp=sharing)

EDIT2:
I'm putting full example, cutted from my original document:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Wstęp} \label{rozdz-wstep} 


\section{Problematyka i zakres pracy}
\indent Niniejsza praca dotyczy odkrywania wiedzy z baz danych, eksploracji danych oraz sztucznej inteligencji, w szczególności obliczeń inteligentnych. \\
\indent Głównym przedmiotem pracy są algorytmy genetyczne oraz problem wykrywania punktów osobliwych (wyjątków) w zbiorach danych. 
Przedstawiona zostanie również analiza praktycznego wykorzystania algorytmu genetycznego do przeszukiwania przestrzeni rozwiązań, w poszukiwaniu wyjątków.
Sprawdzone także zostanie, dla jakich typów danych należy wykorzystywać ewolucyjną eksplorację punktów osobliwych. W końcowej części zawarte zostaną wnioski z przeprowadzonej analizy.\\
\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ c c c }
 cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\ 
 cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\  
 cell7 & cell8 & cell9    
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\indent Podejmując tematykę, o której mowa należy posiadać bardzo dobre zrozumienie problemu przeszukiwania ewolucyjnego. 

Typowe implementacje algorytmów genetycznych nie radzą sobie najlepiej z problemem wykrywania wyjątków, 
a utworzenie specjalistycznych operatorów selekcji, mutacji oraz krzyżowania nie należy do łatwych zadań.\\

\indent Podejmowanie tej tematyki jest bardzo ważne ze względu na to, że różnego rodzaju firmy oraz organizacje zbierają i przechowują ogromne (liczące nawet petabajty) i wciąż rosnące ilości danych, służących do przeprowadzania analiz. 
Aby wydobyć wiedzę z tych danych potrzeba coraz lepszych i wydajniejszych algorytmów. 
Spodziewanym rezultatem pracy, jest odpowiedź, że zastosowanie algorytmu ewolucyjnego do eksploracji wyjątków przyspiesza przeszukiwanie przestrzeni rozwiązań (w porównaniu do pełnego-naiwnego przeszukiwania), przy jednoczesnym zachowaniu akceptowalnej dokładności otrzymywanych wyników.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please, complete the snippet to a full document (MWE). The error is not in the snippet.

Comment: Full document added.

Comment: We need an authorisation…

Comment: It's better to make the document shorter (minimal) and add it to the question. Then the question remains valid, even if the external location is no longer available.

Comment: I have added example. It looks like it works when I remove txfonfs package, but I need it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package `polski` is mostly outdated, just replace the call by

```
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
```

There's a slight complication with `amssymb` that wants to define `\lll`, but there's no need for `amssymb` when `txfonts` is loaded. On the other hand, instead of `txfonts` it's better to load the combination of `newtxtext` and `newtxmath`.

Here's a fixed version, where also the useless `\indent` command and the wrong `\\` for ending paragraphs have been removed.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}

\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Wstęp} \label{rozdz-wstep} 


\section{Problematyka i zakres pracy}

Niniejsza praca dotyczy odkrywania wiedzy z baz danych, eksploracji danych oraz sztucznej 
inteligencji, w szczególności obliczeń inteligentnych.

Głównym przedmiotem pracy są algorytmy genetyczne oraz problem wykrywania punktów osobliwych 
(wyjątków) w zbiorach danych. Przedstawiona zostanie również analiza praktycznego 
wykorzystania algorytmu genetycznego do przeszukiwania przestrzeni rozwiązań, w poszukiwaniu 
wyjątków. Sprawdzone także zostanie, dla jakich typów danych należy wykorzystywać ewolucyjną 
eksplorację punktów osobliwych. W końcowej części zawarte zostaną wnioski z przeprowadzonej 
analizy.

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ c c c }
 cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\ 
 cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\  
 cell7 & cell8 & cell9    
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

Podejmując tematykę, o której mowa należy posiadać bardzo dobre zrozumienie problemu 
przeszukiwania ewolucyjnego.

a utworzenie specjalistycznych operatorów selekcji, mutacji oraz krzyżowania nie należy do 
łatwych zadań.

Podejmowanie tej tematyki jest bardzo ważne ze względu na to, że różnego rodzaju firmy oraz 
organizacje zbierają i przechowują ogromne (liczące nawet petabajty) i wciąż rosnące ilości 
danych, służących do przeprowadzania analiz. Aby wydobyć wiedzę z tych danych potrzeba coraz 
lepszych i wydajniejszych algorytmów. Spodziewanym rezultatem pracy, jest odpowiedź, że 
zastosowanie algorytmu ewolucyjnego do eksploracji wyjątków przyspiesza przeszukiwanie 
przestrzeni rozwiązań (w porównaniu do pełnego-naiwnego przeszukiwania), przy jednoczesnym 
zachowaniu akceptowalnej dokładności otrzymywanych wyników.

\end{document}
```

[image]